# When will Install4J support JRE 12?

Tags: compression, install4j

Packaging my own JRE 12 causes the installer size to increase by 120 MB. Clearly this is not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install4j 8.0 will be released in the next couple of weeks with a completely new way of handling JRE bundles.

Comment: Are the Install4J provided JREs based on OpenJDK?

Comment: Yes, for Java 11+ (where it is relevant) this is already the case with 7.x